# Google Looker Studio: Community Vizualization Problem (Templated Record by Romain Viliard)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, looker-studio, looker

```
{{#IMAGEID}}
    <a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id={{.}}" target="_blank">
    <img class="img" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w1000&id={{.}}"></a>
{{/IMAGEID}}
```

i want to populate some images on the google looker studio using your viz, but somehow i encountered a problem with it, if you look at the code, im looping an array of IMAGEID to populate some clickable images wrapped with the link. i want to render the IMAGEID at two different places, but it only would work if i remove either one of them. like you cant have two '{{.}}' inside a loop.

now i have already tried countless methods to make this work, nested loop, rendering the whole html  which i use another custom field other than IMAGEID itself but no luck at all. hope you can help me out. have a great day sir!